# IE ajax parsing / .includes() & .indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

How can I write this and make it work in IE?

```
var tEvents = eventsJSON.response.Events.filter(function (val, index, array) {
         return val.participating_region.includes(varRegion);
});
totalEvents = tEvents.length;
```

I know the issue is .includes() , just not sure how to write this using .indexOf()

Full code:

```
var varRegion = $('body').data('region'); 

  var eventsJSON = null;
  var totalEvents;
  var virtualEvents;

  $.ajax({
    'url': '/services/getAllEvents',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': function (data) {
     eventsJSON = data;
     parseJSONevents();
    }
  });

  function parseJSONevents() {

    var tEvents = eventsJSON.response.Events.filter(function (val, index, array) {
     return val.participating_region.includes(varRegion);
    });
    totalEvents = tEvents.length;

    $('.in-person-events').text(totalEvents);

    return eventsJSON;

  };
```

Answer (score 1):

`return val.participating_region.indexOf(varRegion) > -1;`

though it is hard to tell without seeing all your relevant code and JSON response structure.

Comment: Thanks. Added full code. I need to return a number that is the total number of matching objects.

Comment: did you try `indexOf(x) > -1`?

Comment: Well I did, and it now works in IE. But only for 1/2 of my numbers in all browsers.  So it works for this script, but the second script with a different ajax call and different JSON file -- but otherwise identical code only produces ones or zeros.